# Use Google Web Fonts in commercial native Cocoa apps?

Tags: macos, cocoa, webfonts, google-webfonts, custom-font

Can **Google Web Fonts** be legally used in **commercial native Cocoa** apps on OS X? Google says officially that one can use the fonts for free on commercial websites, but didn't state specifically the case with native apps.

Currently I've downloaded the font (in `woff` format) from the URL defined in CSS, converted it via an online tool to `ttf` and included it in my project.

Comment: Have you already figured it out?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a legal question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From http://www.google.com/webfonts/#AboutPlace:about

"All of the fonts are Open Source. This means that you are free to share your favorites with friends and colleagues. You can even customize them for your own use, or collaborate with the original designer to improve them. And you can use them in every way you want, privately or commercially — in print, on your computer, or in your websites."

Comment: So yes, I **can** use it commercially.